# Nested Array to Query Params for Filters in Searching

Tags: javascript, ember.js, filter, ember-data

I have:

```
[
    {
        id: // the field to be search
            {
                eq: '1234'  // eq is the operand; 1234 is the keyword
            }
    },
    {
        description:
            {
                like: 'desc'
            }
    }
]
```

How to transform it (in Ember.JS) to query parameters to:

```
?filter[id][eq]=1234&filter[description][like]=desc
```

since the API needed the format like so for the filters?

Comment: What is the id and description?

Comment: will be the field to be search

Comment: I see ember.js and ember-data tags in your question. You might want to include in which way your question is specific to this framework. Are you asking about a way how to map that object to arguments for a `query` request in Ember Data?

Comment: @jelhan yes, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```js
var filter = [
    {
        id: 
            {
                eq: '1234'
            }
    },
    {
        description:
            {
                like: 'desc'
            }
    }
];

var output = '?';

filter.forEach(function (item) {
  output += 'filter';

  Object.keys(item).forEach(function (prop) {
    output += '[' + prop + ']';
  
    Object.keys(item[prop]).forEach(function (subProp) { 
      output += '[' + subProp + ']=' + item[prop][subProp]; 
    });
  });
  
  output += '&';
});

output = output.substring(0, output.length - 1);

console.log(output);
```

You can make a loop through the array and use [Object.key()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with `forEach` function to get the property name and value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. because the first element and second element are different, So I assume that it is always like that.

Here is solution:

```js
const data = [
    {
        id:{
            eq: '1234'
        }
    },
    {
        description:{
            like: 'desc'
        }
    }
];

const [ first, second ] = data;

const queryParams = `?filter[id][eq]=${first['id']['eq']}&filter[description][like]=${second['description']['like']}`;
console.log(queryParams);
```

Then the output will be:

```js
?filter[id][eq]=1234&filter[description][like]=desc
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 way.

```js
var arr = [
    {
        id: 
            {
                eq: '1234'
            }
    },
    {
        description:
            {
                like: 'desc'
            }
    }
];


const url = '?' + arr.map(filter => {
  // assuming single key, so using pop(). 
  // Change accordingly if your input array schema changes.
  const major = Object.keys(filter).pop();
  const minor = Object.keys(filter[major]).pop();
  return `filter[${major}][${minor}]=${filter[major][minor]}`;
}).join('&');

console.log(url);
// output: ?filter[id][eq]=1234&filter[description][like]=desc
```

Comment: do you have an ember.js solution for this?